# Could Hela destroy Captain America's shield?

Tags: marvel

[image: Thor and Captain America comic]

Thor's hammer is made of Uru, one of the strongest materials in the Marvel universes. Captain America's shield could withstand Thor's hammer attack, so both are strong. Both of them can't destroy each other but, Hela easily broke Thor's hammer. Does that mean Hela could break Cap's shield?

Comment: I've attempted to make your post more readable and more understandable. Hopefully I haven't accidentally removed anything. Note: the original version of the question referenced the Marvel Cinematic Universe, but I don't recall if Thor's hammer was ever explicitly said to be made of Uru in the MCU, or if that's a comic thing.

Comment: Even if it's  not made  if uru like you said it's very strong and hela broke it easily  so can hela could break  Caps shield  too

Comment: Why not...[**It's been broken many times before**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134939/who-other-than-thanos-has-ever-broken-captain-americas-shield)

Comment: Thanos was able to break the shield with the blade of the Thanos-Copter.

Comment: "Both of them can't destroy each other" — I mean, maybe they can. We need the TVA to get a few Thanos variants to smash them together repeatedly and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

### It is extremely likely that it can be.

Captain America's shield has been broken by Thanos (in *Avengers: Endgame*) in the Marvel Cinematic Universe. It has also been broken several times in the comics, and seeing as it is comparable strength to Mjolnir - we know this because Mjolnir and the shield collide many times in the MCU, and neither have broken from these collisions - and Mjolnir can be broken by Hela, **it is a reasonable assumption that Cap's shield can be broken by Hela.** There is no evidence of this happening in the MCU or the comics, however, and it is entirely possible that it is impossible, but:

- other extraterrestrials have broken the shield
- Vibranium is not the strongest material in the universe

So, all in all, **it's entirely likely but has never happened in any canon timeline to the movies or the comics.**