# Can Hela destroy vibranium-made equipment?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, vibranium, black-panther-2018

To what extent can Hela's powers break equipment? Uru is definitely a strong material used for Thor's hammer. With that being said, do her powers include destroying vibranium? Or more specifically, can she break Black Panther's suit or anything at all in Wakanda that is made of vibranium?

Comment: This seems a dupe of: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181620/could-hela-destroy-captain-americas-shield

Comment: @Loki Very similar, but different in that 1) This is MCU exclusive, and 2) Captain America's shield is made of different elements with different stated properties in the mainstream comics (true adamantium, which is a vibranium/steel alloy with unknown catalyst) and movies (vibranium). So, maybe?

Comment: @Mwr247 Indeed and that's why I didn't vote to close it. Also, the question I linked doesn't have an answer, so perhaps we get with this one. Regarding the MCU part, the answer is don't know as Hela and Black Panther/Cap haven't crossed paths.

Comment: Vibranium and Adamantium can be broken by magic.. and Hela *is* magic.. so yes.. she can break vibranium-made shields, panther suits everything

Comment: I do not think we will ever know, as hell is dead? (It's marvel, death is not always dead, and we did not see her cold corpse, but she's probably dead)